# keras.preprocessing.image - load only certain images (whose filename contains some string)

Tags: python, keras

I have a binary classification problem. Given an image, I want to predict whether it belongs to `class_1` or `class_2`.

The training data is located in the subfolders `class_1` and `class_2` under `.../data/train/`, i.e.

`.../data/train/class_1`

`.../data/train/class_2`

To import the training data, I am currently using

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory('.../data/train/')
```

Now, let's say that my training data is further divided into to two different datasets, but stored in the same directories. The dataset which a training sample belongs to is specified in the filename, i.e. each filename contains either `AAA` or `BBB`. Now I want to load only the training samples whose filenames include `AAA`. How would I do that without having to create new directories?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know is by auto-generating a new subfolder and calling the Generator on that Subfolder. A Function to Autogenerate a sorted Subfolder shouldn't be too hard...

Let's say you store the Path, where all the images saved in a variable like this :

`path = r".../data/train/class_1"`

And Your identifiers in a list:

`identifier = ["AAA","BBB",...]`

Then you create the new Subfolder for each Identifier:

```
for id in identifier:
    new_path = path + "\\" + id
    os.makedirs(path + \\ + id) #creating the subfolder
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if Path(path + "\\" + file).is_file(): #making sure, that you'r just grabbing the files, and not similar named folders
            if file.count(id) >= 0: # each file that conatins the identifier at least once
                shutil.move(path + "\\" + file,new_path + "\\" + file) #moving the file to the new subfolder
```

Then you can call the Generator on the specific folder you want to access...

I hope that helps if you have any questions feel free to ask :D

Comment: Thanks! That is actually what I am doing right now, but ideally, I want to avoid doing this. Right now I am working with images, and in this case it is "okey". However, I will soon start working with video-files, and creating copies of all the data is not really optimal due to the large memory usage.

Comment: I mean you don't need to produce copies, simply moving them should be enough I guess, works faster and saves memory
But yea you are right, it doesn't seem to be an optimal solution

Comment: Reasonable suggestion, however, I still want the files to be located where they currently are. Of course I could move them and then move them back, but would like a "prettier" solution. ^^

Comment: You could try to use `.flow()` instead of `flow_from_directory()`. Then you would have to load all the images into a `numpy`-array and let `.flow()`take the images from there. Then you would just produce temporarily copies in the array, might work faster

Comment: This was what I had in mind, but it was not completely clear how I would do it. Maybe it is straightforward, but if you could help me out, I would highly appreciate it. :)

Comment: on which part are you struggling? creating the Array or using the `flow`-command?

Comment: I know how to read in the images and create an numpy array, but I am struggeling with the flow-command